# Zend framework does not care about the Custom Route specified

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

I created a router and added to the controller like this

```
public function _initRouting() {          
    // Get Front Controller Instance         
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();  
    // Get Router
    $router = $front -> getRouter();
    $routePage = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/page/:action/:cat/:parent/:id', array(
        'controller' => 'page',
        'action'    => 'list',
        'cat'       => 'general',
        'parent'    => '0',
        'module'    => 'default'
    ));
    $router -> addRoute('page', $routePage);
}
```

First this router is not doing anything, whenever I navigation to
`/page/list/general/0/1`, it takes the standard route, not the new route.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is the front controller resource has not been "bootstrapped" prior to your init method.

You should at least bootstrap and retrieve the front controller resource

```
protected function _initRouting()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
    // etc
```

Why don't you just skip creating a bootstrap init method and configure the router resource in your application config?

```
resources.router.routes.page.route = "page/:action/:cat/:parent/:id"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.controller = "page"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.action = "list"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.cat = "general"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.parent = "0"
```

As a test, I added the above config and created a `PageController` with this `listAction`

```
public function listAction()
{
    Zend_Debug::dump($this->getRequest()->getParams());
    exit;
}
```

Calling `page/list/general/0/1` yields

```
array(6) {
  ["action"] => string(4) "list"
  ["cat"] => string(7) "general"
  ["parent"] => string(1) "0"
  ["id"] => string(1) "1"
  ["module"] => string(7) "default"
  ["controller"] => string(4) "page"
}
```

Comment: @mrN I can't duplicate your problem (see my edited answer). Do you have any other routes defined?

Comment: Yes, I do have other routes defined as well, but I am giving a seperate name of every route, so I dont think they should class like that.

Comment: @mrN The order of your routes is most likely is the problem. You need to define them in order of least to most specific. See the *Reverse Matching* note on [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Comment: I will check it, but could you help me. on [this question also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344518/dynamic-default-value-selection-in-zend-form-element-multiselect)